# facebook no button for share in fb official application

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

http://s-nowproject.ru/GREET-7D841B7FB2E6E912B1B35B3B112545F7 - example

When someone try share with facebook, all ok.

But when share with Iphone 5/6 there is no share button, because link open official app without share button. 
Only preview.

Is it problem with facebook app?

What I see: [image]

What I want: [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not working variant, but without errors, and without button for share:

```
FB.ui({
        method: 'share',
        href: getUrlA(this)
    }, function (response) {

    });
```

Working variant:

```
FB.login(function(response) {
    FB.ui({
        method: 'share',
        href: getUrlA(this)
    }, function (response) {

    });
});
```